# how to remove wireguard

Tags: wireguard

my os is ubuntu 20

i try remove wireguard

```
sudo apt remove wireguard
sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
```

```
Package 'wireguard' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

```
$ locate wireguard

/snap/core18/2667/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/__pycache__/cc_wireguard.cpython-36.pyc
/snap/core18/2667/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_wireguard.py
/snap/core20/1778/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/__pycache__/cc_wireguard.cpython-38.pyc
/snap/core20/1778/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_wireguard.py
/snap/core22/484/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/__pycache__/cc_wireguard.cpython-310.pyc
/snap/core22/484/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_wireguard.py
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireguard
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-57-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireguard/wireguard.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireguard
/usr/lib/modules/5.15.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireguard/wireguard.ko
/usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/wireguard.yaml
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-57/drivers/net/wireguard
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-57/drivers/net/wireguard/Makefile
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-57/include/uapi/linux/wireguard.h
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-57/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-57/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard/netns.sh
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-57/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard/qemu
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-57/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard/qemu/Makefile
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58/drivers/net/wireguard
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58/drivers/net/wireguard/Makefile
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58/include/uapi/linux/wireguard.h
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard/netns.sh
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard/qemu
/usr/src/linux-hwe-5.15-headers-5.15.0-58/tools/testing/selftests/wireguard/qemu/Makefile
/var/lib/dpkg/info/wireguard-tools.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/wireguard-tools.postrm
```

i try delete file

```
$ rm -rf cloudinit

rm: cannot remove 'cloudinit/__init__.py': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove 'cloudinit/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc': Read-only file system
```

Comment: Please be precise with details; 20 doesn't include an `apt` command as the *year* products are *snap* only.  You're probably asking about either Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or Ubuntu 20.10 (a *year.month* product) as they can use *deb* and *snap* packages..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i remove from Manage WireGuard VPN from Desktop

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3612/wireguard-indicator/

Answer (score 3):

Technically speaking, Wireguard *is* removed from your system.  What you're seeing leftover in `cloudinit` (which is a *snap* so you can't just remove files) and in the Kernel packages you see (which are headers and source code for development purposes and driver compiling via DKMS and such) are the *kernel-level components* that Wireguard relies on that're baked into the kernel and other packages.

The presence of `wireguard` in filenames, tests, drivers, etc. does not mean Wireguard is installed on your system.  If you've done `sudo apt purge wireguard wireguard-tools` then you can safely ignore the res of the 'located files'.  Note also the `locate` command is *not real time updated* - it only updates about once a day at boot time so you may be seeing files that don't actually exist or such anymore.

Suffice it to say, if you've removed the `wireguard` package, wireguard isn't present on your system anymore, despite references to it in other filenames, etc. which are not indicative of it still being present on your system.

Comment: i run sudo apt purge wireguard wireguard-tools
it success to remove wireguard-tools
and it still show in menu and still show wireguard

Comment: @Hosamalzagh what menu are you seeing wireguard in?

Comment: https://files.fm/u/wrbgdzed8

Comment: @Hosamalzagh did you add those VPN configurations via network manager and its wireguard profile options?  If so, you still have to *remove* them from Network Manager's configurations - it can still show configurations even if the core software and libraries required for them are removed.  Those are *independent* of `wireguard` being installed or not. (and trying to turn one on should hard-fail without wireguard installed anyways)

Comment: i not add to  network manager i never run it

Comment: If you execute `sudo snap refresh` does that app show up?

Comment: @darth_epoxy All snaps up to date.

Comment: Sorry mate my bad. Type `snap list` and does that app show up? If it was installed via snap then the apt commands obviously won't effect it. It was possible (maybe still is) to have the same app installed via apt and by snap.

Comment: @darth_epoxy
not show in install (snap list)

Comment: @xpredo what is that application in your screenshot?  It's possible that's a separate application *not* installed via `apt` that won't be 'removed' when you remove the core wireguard components because it's a separate third party application.  (It looks like you're using a third party application that isn't governed by apt in this case, or snaps)